# C# API Rotas (Iniciante)

Tags: c#, api, mvc

Criei um novo projeto do tipo: ASP.NET Web Application - WEB API

Crei um novo controller, porém, não estou conseguindo diferenciar as ACTIONS.

Se eu tenho mais de um método do tipo GET, na hora que eu requisito recebo o erro:

```
"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nIndex on type DGBar.Controllers.TestController\r\nTeste on type DGBar.Controllers.TestController"
```

A rota configurada é a padrão:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Acredito que o erro esteja na rota, onde não foi configurarda o endereço com "api" mas não consegui fazer os ajustes necessários para que funcionasse.

Estou requisitando "https://localhost:44398/api/Test/Teste" mas a action TESTE está sendo completamente ignorada.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Obrigado.
https://github.com/zecaloteiro/DGBar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DGBar.Controllers {
  public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Index() {
      return Json("Index");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Teste() {
      return Json("Teste");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: consegue postar os métodos que tem na sua controller também?

Comment: Opa, claro. Editei o post. Muito obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

Nas suas configurações, vai ficar o default:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Já na sua controller, você deve usar duas nomenclaturas:

```
 [RoutePrefix("test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {    
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("index")]
        public string Index(string No)
        {
            try
            {
                return No;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("teste")]
        public string Teste(string No)
        {
            try
            {
                return No;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Aí para consumir utilize:

`endereco/api/test/index` ou `endereco/api/test/teste`

Você pode ler mais sobre na documentação oficial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou. A notação Route("") substitui o  [HttpGet("teste")] do .net Core.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar suas próprias rotas da seguinte forma.

```
namespace DGBar.Controllers {
  public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Index() {
      return Json("Index");
    }
    [HttpGet("teste")]
    public IHttpActionResult Teste() {
      return Json("Teste");
    }
  }
}
```

O seu erro ocorre por terem dois métodos com o verbo GET sem diferenciação entre eles.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Mas se eu utilizo a notação que você sugeriu, obtenho erro: 'HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Acredito que meu conceito de API REST está um pouco equivocado pois após pesquisar acredito que minha estrutura deveria ter apenas tipos de chamada (get, post, put, delete, etc) dentro do controller e não precisar criar {controle}/{action}